# Problem showing that $\chi(G) \le 3$ constructing $G$ from a finite set of lines and maybe using greedy algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, plane-geometry

Consider a set of lines in the plane such that there are not three that
intersect at the same point, and construct a graph $G$ whose vertices are the intersections of the lines, and where two vertices are adjacent if they appear consecutively on the same line. Show that $$\chi(G) \le 3$$

So I understand how $G$ is constructed, I had an idea from rotating the plane and coloring from left to right but at the end it didn't work.

Obviously the plane is in $\mathbb{R^2}$

I saw I maybe can do it using the greedy algorithm but using this give at most $Max degree + 1$ colors, how can I use it to only use 3 colors?

Is there really a way to color $G$ with at most 3 colors?

Comment: If no three lines intersect in a point, then what is $d(v)$, for any $v$?

Comment: Oh sorry I confused my self, I forgot to put maximun degree instead  of $d(v)$

Comment: @LetGBeTheGraph, the degree can be as high as 4, since there can be edges 'both ways' on each intersecting line.

Comment: Yes I have notice that, but is there a way that $G$ can be a to most 3-colored? I have tried to use the greedy algorith but in some cases I found 2 points in the same $y$-coordinate

Comment: Your idea of using the greedy coloring algorithm is good. Can you think of a way to order the vertices of such a graph so that each vertex in the ordering has at most 2 earlier neighbors? Why would this be sufficient to prove your statement (that $\chi(G) \leq 3$)?

Comment: Mmm I was early thinking "rotating" the plane, in the purpose to don't have two vertices in the same $y$-coordinate

Comment: I don't know if you've gotten this yet or not, but *yes*, that's a great idea.

Comment: I'm close to finish thanks for the help!